# how to get a query params in react native deep linking

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-deep-linking

I have implemented deep linking in my app. My app is opening using added links but unable to get query params from one link

here is the code of my deep linking config

```js
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['demo://'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Signup: {
        path: 'SignUp',
      },
      SignupInvitation: {
        path: 'user/invite/invite_code/:invitecode',
        parse: {
          invitecode: (invitecode: string) => {
            console.log('Code ', invitecode);
            storeToken(invitecode);
            return `${invitecode}`;
          },
        },
      },
      ResetPassword: {
        path: 'reset_password',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

here is the complete link:

```sh
https://myapp.com/reset_password?access-token=abcdw&client=abcdef&client_id=abcdef&config=default&expiry=1646292840&reset_password=true&token=abcd&uid=abc@gmail.com
```

I want to get access-token, client, and uid from this link.
how can I get it?

Comment: but looks like you didn't do anything to get params for path "ResetPassword" ? like SignupInvitation path?

Comment: Yes because i didn't find any way to do that

Comment: But you already did it for "SignupInvitation" path. Am I missing something? You should just do the same things for "ResetPassword" path.

Comment: No in signup invitation case,  invite code is the part of URL :
https://app.com/user/invite/invite_code/Du2Gagd3Czwzky  but in resetPassword case, its different

Comment: here --- > [https://dev.to/kapilgorve/react-native-how-to-parse-url-query-parameters-kp2](https://dev.to/kapilgorve/react-native-how-to-parse-url-query-parameters-kp2)

Comment: yes its different so you should just change the path with its params. like path: reset_password/:access-token.

Comment: tried but URL is changed, so didn't work in this way

Comment: Dear @MuhammadUmar, Ahmad is my friend, the answer post I mean.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my working example:

navigations.ts

```
Loading: {
  path:
    'Loading/:routeName/:key1?/:value1?/:key2?/:value2?/:key3?/:value3?',
  screen: Loading,
},
```

Loading.tsx

```
const Loading = ({{ navigation }}) => {
const routeName = navigation.getParam("routeName")
useEffect(() => {
  const params = {
    [navigation.getParam("key1")]: navigation.getParam("value1"),
    [navigation.getParam("key2")]: navigation.getParam("value2"),
    [navigation.getParam("key3")]: navigation.getParam("value3"),
  }
  console.log({ params })
})
navigation.navigate(routeName, params)
}
```

and finally the link I use for returning back to the app

```
billing-app://Loading/InviteScreen/refresh/true
```

Comment: Brother you are using optional parameters in route, these are not query params, please check my link. I need query params not dynamic optional routing params